# Multiple AND conditions and OR conditions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from two table using below query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id,a.company_name,a.company_logo 
FROM   eco_company_profile a, eco_product_desc ep 
where (a.status='t' AND ep.status='t' AND a.`pro_thunderx` ='yes') 
OR    (a.status='t' AND ep.status='t' AND ep.`pro_thunderx` ='yes') 
order by a.company_name
```

But its returning all the company details from the table.
I need to retrieve all company details with below condition,

```
eco_company_profile.status =t and
eco_company_profile.pro_thunderx =yes and
eco_product_desc.status =t
```

Or

```
eco_company_profile.status =t and
eco_product_desc.pro_thunderx =yes and
eco_product_desc.status =t
```

Comment: What's wrong with your query? Is there any column to joint `eco_company_profile ` and `eco_product_desc`?

Comment: It looks like if you're doing a cartesian product. First, you need to add a clause `JOIN` between the two tables, like a condition for establishing the relation of both tables.  Maybe, you even need a third table that contents this relation, a table that defines the products of a company.

Comment: I am retrieving data by combining two tables with certain conditions.

Comment: 1st condition : `eco_company_profile.status =t and
eco_company_profile.pro_thunderx =yes and
eco_product_desc.status =t`

Comment: 2nd condition : `eco_company_profile.status =t and
eco_product_desc.pro_thunderx =yes and
eco_product_desc.status =t`

Comment: You realise that 2/3 of the condition are the same ? So you just need `where a.status='t' AND ep.status='t' AND (a.pro_thunderx = 'yes' or ep.pro_thunderx ='yes')`. Of course, you should prefer a `JOIN` instead of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id,a.company_name,a.company_logo 
FROM   eco_company_profile a, eco_product_desc ep 
where a.status='t' AND ep.status='t' AND a.`pro_thunderx` ='yes' OR ep.`pro_thunderx` ='yes'
order by a.company_name
```

Comment: This query also returning all company details

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id,a.company_name,a.company_logo 
FROM   eco_company_profile a, eco_product_desc ep 
where a.status='t' AND ep.status='t' AND (a.pro_thunderx ='yes' OR ep.pro_thunderx ='yes') 
order by a.company_name
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally i got solution. forgot to add unique id for both table
  `SELECT DISTINCT a.id,a.company_name,a.company_logo FROM eco_company_profile a, eco_product_desc ep WHERE (ep.status='t' AND a.status='t' AND ep.pro_thunderx ='yes' and a.id=ep.cid) OR (a.status='t' AND a.pro_thunderx ='yes') ORDER BY a.company_name`